# Ajax call always fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my jquery script, the ajax alway fails and I really don't understand why.
Here is the call:

```
<script>


            function myFunction()
            {
            var time = document.getElementById('yearsemployed').value + "years";
            var baseurlstring = "http://www.quickinsure.co.za/LeadService/Service.asmx/SubmitLatestLoanLead?";

            var paramfirstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
            var paramlastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
            var paramemailaddress = document.getElementById('emailaddress').value;
            var paramcellnumber = document.getElementById('cellnumber').value;
            var paramidnumber = document.getElementById('idnumber').value;
            var paramnetsalary = document.getElementById('netsalary').value;
            var paramgrosssalary = document.getElementById('grosssalary').value;
            var paramloanammount = document.getElementById('loanammount').value;
            var paramdebtreview = "FALSE";
            if(document.getElementById('debtreview').checked == true)
            {
            paramdebtreview = "TRUE";
            }
            var e = document.getElementById("bank");
            var parambank = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            var params = {
            UserId:100405,
            Firstname:paramfirstname,
            Surname:paramlastname,
            Email:paramemailaddress,
            CellNo:paramcellnumber,
            WorkNo:paramcellnumber,
            IdNo:paramidnumber,
            NetSalary:paramnetsalary,
            GrossSalary:paramgrosssalary,
            LoanAmount:paramloanammount,
            EmploymentTime:time,
            UnderDebtReview:paramdebtreview,
            Bank:parambank,
            SubId:"affcoza_1829_397",
            TestMode:"TRUE"
            };
            str = jQuery.param( params );

            var callbackurl = baseurlstring + str;

            getloanapplicationcallback(callbackurl);

            }

            function successCallBack(returnData){
            window.location = 'http://www.lowcreditloans.co.za/thank-you-for-submitting/';
            }

            function errorCallBack(){

            window.location = 'http://www.lowcreditloans.co.za/error-processing-request/';

            }

            function getloanapplicationcallback(callbackurl)
            {
            // this will generate another thread to run in another function
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: callbackurl,
            type: 'get',
            success: successCallBack,
            error: errorCallBack
            });
            }

          </script>
```

And here is the php:

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <div id="et_contact_left">

                <h3 style="padding-bottom:10px">Personal Details:</h3>



                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">First Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="firstname" value="" tabindex="1" name="firstname" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="lastname" value="" tabindex="2" name="lastname" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Email:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="emailaddress" value="" tabindex="3" name="emailaddress" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Cell Number:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="cellnumber" value="" tabindex="4" name="cellnumber" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Id Number:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="idnumber" value="" tabindex="5" name="idnumber" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Years Employed:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="yearsemployed" value="0" tabindex="6" name="yearsemployed" class="input"/>
                  <label for="title">Months Employed:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="monthsemployed" value="0" tabindex="7" name="monthsemployed" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <h3>Employment Details:</h3>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Monthly Gross Salary:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="grosssalary" value="" tabindex="8" name="grosssalary" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Monthly Net Salary:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="netsalary" value="" tabindex="9" name="netsalary" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Loan Ammount:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="loanammount" value="" tabindex="10" name="loanammount" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Total Monthly Expneses:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="grosssalary" value="" tabindex="11" name="grosssalary" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Bank:</label>
                  <select name="bank" id="bank" tabindex="6">
                    <option value="0">First National Bank</option>
                    <option value="1">ABSA Bank</option>
                    <option value="2">Nedbank</option>
                    <option value="3">Standerd Bank</option>
                    <option value="4">Capitec Bank</option>
                    <option value="5">Bidvest Bank</option>
                    <option value="6">RMB</option>
                    <option value="7">Investec Bank</option>
                    <option value="8" selected="selected">Other</option>
                  </select>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Paydate:</label>
                  <input type="text" required="true" id="grosssalary" value="25" tabindex="12" name="grosssalary" class="input"/>
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Are you under debt review?</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="debtreview" name="debtreview" value="" />
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">Preform Credit Check with Id-Number?</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="creditcheck" name="creditcheck" checked="checked" />
                </p>

                <p class="clearfix">
                  <label for="title">I Accept the Terms and Conditions</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="termsandconditions" name="termsandconditions" checked="checked" />
                </p>

              </div> <!-- et_contact_left -->

              <input type="submit" value="Submit Application" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" class="et_contact_submit" onclick=" myFunction()" />

            </form>
```

Comment: can OP include response from url?

Comment: I suggest passing data in a separate parameter of ajax call not in the URL itself.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? What's the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
type:"GET", 
url:callbackurl,
success:function(){
  successCallBack();
},
error:function(){
 errorCallBack();
}
});
```

Secondly you must use `return false`, `preventDefault` or `type=button` instead of `type=submit` it will submit to your `form action` which is empty

Answer (score 0):

To avoid browsers default submit behavior, put a

```
return false;
```

either in your onclick or at the end of the function. Otherwise the form will be submitted => action = "" means POST the form data to the current url.

Answer (score 0):

Use type="button",preventDefault to alter the default behaviour of form. In the above script you are not anything to alter the behaviour of Form.